# Spring Integration web service client not signing key for outgoing message

Tags: spring-integration

I am currently using Spring Integration web service client and its works fine for web service end point with http call.
Now i am trying to call https end point with signing client key to outgoing messages with server cerificate from cacerts(defaut).We have added server certificate in cacerts and we keep authentication key in separate keysore file to sign/add keys to outgoing messages.Its binding with certificate from cacerts as expected.For sign/add key to the outgoing message alonwith server certificate, I have added below code in Spring Integration xml.

```
<bean id="keyStore" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.support.KeyStoreFactoryBean">
 <property name="location">
           <value>classpath:client.jks</value>
       </property>
     <property name="password" value="test123"/>
    </bean>
<bean id="keyStoreHandler" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.KeyStoreCallbackHandler">
        <property name="keyStore" ref="keyStore"/>
        <property name="privateKeyPassword" value="test123"/>
</bean>
```

After adding above code, Authentication key is not binding with outbound gateway message and there is no exception also. Please help me what i am missing here.Itneed to add/sign authentication keys from myown keystore file alongwith server certificate. I really appreciate your input on this.

Please refer my final Spring integration xml.

```
<bean id="xshMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory" />

    <si:channel id="xshReqChannel" />
<si:channel id="xshResChannel" />

    <si:gateway id="xshProvider" service-interface="comm.sd.xshProvider" default-request-channel="xshReqChannel"  default-reply-channel="xshResChannel"    
       />

<ws:outbound-gateway id="xshProvider" 
        marshaller="xshMarshaller"
        unmarshaller="xshMarshaller"
        message-sender="xshMessageSender"
        message-factory="xshMessageFactory"
        request-channel="xshReqChannel"
        reply-channel="xshResChannel"
         uri="${xshEndPoint}" />

        <bean id="keyStore" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.support.KeyStoreFactoryBean">
            <property name="location">
           <value>classpath:client.jks</value>
       </property>
     <property name="password" value="test123"/>
    </bean>
<bean id="keyStoreHandler" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.KeyStoreCallbackHandler">
        <property name="keyStore" ref="keyStore"/>
        <property name="privateKeyPassword" value="test123" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do be honest, I have never done anything similar, but according to the Spring WS [Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/security.html#security-certificate-authentication) you go right way. What you have missed is just a configuration for a `XwsSecurityInterceptor` bean and it injection to the `<ws:outbound-gateway>` using `interceptor` attribute.

Would be great if you do the solution and share it with us to add it to our [Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ws-outbound-gateway).